# Beginner SQL: How can I combine these SQL queries to return two sum columns side-by-side?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I currently have two small queries and I'm trying to combine them. First gives me the sum budget hours on a job. Second gives me sum actual hours.

When I tried to combine these, I used two left joins, and ended up with way too many budget hours. Something is going wrong with my group-by or join logic, but I am not sure which.

```
--Query for Budget Hours 
SELECT  bdglin.recnum, --this is jobnum
        actrec.jobnme, 
        SUM(hrsbdg) AS budgethours
FROM    bdglin
LEFT JOIN actrec ON actrec.recnum = bdglin.recnum
WHERE actrec.jobtyp = 2 
GROUP BY bdglin.recnum, actrec.jobnme
ORDER BY recnum


--Query for Actual hours 
SELECT  jobcst.jobnum,
        actrec.jobnme,
        SUM(jobcst.csthrs) AS actualhours
FROM    jobcst
LEFT JOIN actrec ON actrec.recnum = jobcst.jobnum
WHERE actrec.jobtyp = 2
GROUP BY jobnum, actrec.jobnme
ORDER BY jobnum

 --Failed attempt to combine them, returns like 50,000 hours for a job
SELECT  bdglin.recnum, 
        actrec.jobnme, 
        SUM(bdglin.hrsbdg) AS BudgetHours, 
        SUM(jobcst.csthrs) AS ActualHrs 
FROM    bdglin 
LEFT JOIN actrec ON actrec.recnum = bdglin.recnum
LEFT JOIN jobcst ON jobcst.jobnum = bdglin.recnum
WHERE actrec.jobtyp = 2 
GROUP BY bdglin.recnum, actrec.jobnme
ORDER BY jobnme
```

Comment: The simplest thing would be to use each of your queries as a `derived table`, and then join those together.

Comment: First query is not in fact a left join as you are using column in where...

Comment: `GROUP BY` each table in a separate derived table. Then JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to roll your two working queries into CTEs and then join the CTEs. That is a technique you should learn (though it is not always the best approach so don't blindly apply this or any other pattern).

```
with budgethrs as ( 
   SELECT  bdglin.recnum as jobnum, actrec.jobnme, 
        SUM(hrsbdg) AS budgethours
    FROM bdglin 
    JOIN actrec ON actrec.recnum = bdglin.recnum
    WHERE actrec.jobtyp = 2 
    GROUP BY bdglin.recnum, actrec.jobnme
), 
actualhrs as (
   SELECT  jobcst.jobnum, actrec.jobnme,
        SUM(jobcst.csthrs) AS actualhours
   FROM jobcst
   JOIN actrec ON actrec.recnum = jobcst.jobnum
   WHERE actrec.jobtyp = 2
   GROUP BY jobnum, actrec.jobnme
)
select isnull(jobcst.jobnum, actualhrsjobnum) as jobnum, 
       ...
from budgethrs full outer join actualhrs
  on budgethrs.jobnum = actualhrs.jobnum 
 and budgethrs.jobnme = actualhrs.jobnme 
order by ...
;
```

Notice the full outer join. There is a reason for that which I leave to you to discover and validate. Because of the full join you need to use CASE expressions to "pick a winner" to handle un-matched rows properly. To more fully understand that, just include all the columns (temporarily) in the select list and test with a good sample data set. You will need job numbers that have both budget and actual numbers, only budget numbers, and only actual numbers in your test data.

Also notice that I changed your outer joins to inner joins. As already noted, referring to the unpreserved table (e.g., actrec) in the WHERE clause logically converts those into inner joins. Let's not try to fool any reader.

I can see a much more efficient way to write the query but this is a quick and dirty method for achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks, ended up solving it but not sure how to add the finished code here. Probably still inefficient but oh well

Your point about efficiency was helpful! Spent some time learning subselects and those made life a lot easier